# AttributeError: 'res.partner' object has no attribute 'check_vat_ve' - Odoo v10 community

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-8, odoo-10

I'm inheriting `res.partner`:

```
class ResPartner(models.Model):
_name = 'res.partner'
_inherit = 'res.partner'

@api.model
def check_vat_ve(self, vat): #, context=None
    """ Check Venezuelan VAT number, locally called RIF.
    RIF: JXXXXXXXXX RIF VENEZOLAN
         IDENTIFICATION CARD: VXXXXXXXXX
         FOREIGN IDENTIFICATION CARD: EXXXXXXXXX
    """

    #if context is None:
        #context = {}
    if re.search(r'^[VJEGP][0-9]{9}$', vat):
        return True
    if re.search(r'^([VE][0-9]{1,8}|[D][0-9]{9})$', vat):
        return True
    return False
```

As You can see, there is a method called `chack_vat_ve`, and it's declared on `res.partner` object.

Now, I have this other (wizard) method which is for a button:

```
@api.multi
def search_partner_seniat(self):
    """ Check vat of the partner and update iva rate
    """
    self.ensure_one()
    vat = self.vat.upper()
    res = {
        'name': _('The requested contributor does not exist'),
        'vat_subjected': False,
        'vat': vat,
        'wh_iva_agent': False,
        'wh_iva_rate': 0.0
    }

    if 'VE' in vat:
        vat = vat[2:]

    # assumption: both methods in new api style
    if self.env['res.partner'].check_vat_ve(vat): 
        res = self.env['seniat.url']._dom_giver(vat)  
    self.write(res)
```

Every time I click on this, it throws me:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/kristian/.virtualenvs/odoov10/lib/python2.7/site-packages/odoo-10.0rc1c_20161005-py2.7.egg/odoo/http.py", line 638, in _handle_exception
return super(JsonRequest, self)._handle_exception(exception)
File "/home/kristian/.virtualenvs/odoov10/lib/python2.7/site-packages/odoo-10.0rc1c_20161005-py2.7.egg/odoo/http.py", line 675, in dispatch
result = self._call_function(**self.params)
File "/home/kristian/.virtualenvs/odoov10/lib/python2.7/site-packages/odoo-10.0rc1c_20161005-py2.7.egg/odoo/http.py", line 331, in _call_function
return checked_call(self.db, *args, **kwargs)
File "/home/kristian/.virtualenvs/odoov10/lib/python2.7/site-packages/odoo-10.0rc1c_20161005-py2.7.egg/odoo/service/model.py", line 119, in wrapper
return f(dbname, *args, **kwargs)
File "/home/kristian/.virtualenvs/odoov10/lib/python2.7/site-packages/odoo-10.0rc1c_20161005-py2.7.egg/odoo/http.py", line 324, in checked_call
result = self.endpoint(*a, **kw)
File "/home/kristian/.virtualenvs/odoov10/lib/python2.7/site-packages/odoo-10.0rc1c_20161005-py2.7.egg/odoo/http.py", line 933, in __call__
return self.method(*args, **kw)
File "/home/kristian/.virtualenvs/odoov10/lib/python2.7/site-packages/odoo-10.0rc1c_20161005-py2.7.egg/odoo/http.py", line 504, in response_wrap
response = f(*args, **kw)
File "/home/kristian/odoov10/odoo-10.0rc1c-20161005/odoo/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 866, in call_button
action = self._call_kw(model, method, args, {})
File "/home/kristian/odoov10/odoo-10.0rc1c-20161005/odoo/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 854, in _call_kw
return call_kw(request.env[model], method, args, kwargs)
File "/home/kristian/.virtualenvs/odoov10/lib/python2.7/site-packages/odoo-10.0rc1c_20161005-py2.7.egg/odoo/api.py", line 681, in call_kw
return call_kw_multi(method, model, args, kwargs)
File "/home/kristian/.virtualenvs/odoov10/lib/python2.7/site-packages/odoo-10.0rc1c_20161005-py2.7.egg/odoo/api.py", line 672, in call_kw_multi
result = method(recs, *args, **kwargs)
File "/home/kristian/odoov10/gilda/l10n_ve_fiscal_requirements/wizard/search_info_partner_seniat.py", line 63, in search_partner_seniat
if self.env['res.partner'].check_vat_ve(vat):  
AttributeError: 'res.partner' object has no attribute 'check_vat_ve'
```

I'm almost sure there is some error with the wizard method, since I'm migrating these modules, from v8 to v10 community, they're still kind of buggy.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try removing the **_name = 'res.partner'** attribute because that seems unnecessary and then let us know.

Comment: Hi Walid, Thank You, the problem persist :(

Comment: I think that somehow the 'chack_vat_ve' function parameter isn't correct 'self.env['res.partner'].check_vat_ve(vat): ' there's something wrong on that, I can't figure it out

Comment: I mean, I think in that fashion, it should call something like a field, but it's actually a method, I'm still not fond on v10 api

Comment: Maybe chack_vat_ve is not browsable?

Comment: I think this is due to the fact that the model which contains check_vat_ve was commented on __init__ file, lol, I'm sorry.

Comment: you mean you did not import it in the `__init__` file. do you still have the problem

Comment: No, I have some other issue, yeah it was the sentence into the '__init__' file, from . import file :) Thank You

Comment: Guys, please update the question and the answer. In this state both are useless for others. Removing `_name` in inherited odoo business objects is just a wrong answer, that will do nothing.